# pig example apache [input path doesngt exist]

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, hdfs, apache-pig

I am trying out apache pig on my local desktop.

I was hoping the tutorial on the apache page to be precise or call out the steps. 
I installed pig and am just trying to paste the sample code: from here http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/setup.html#Sample+Code

```
Local Mode

$ pig -x local
Mapreduce Mode

$ pig
or
$ pig -x mapreduce
For either mode, the Grunt shell is invoked and you can enter commands at the prompt. The results are displayed to your terminal screen (if DUMP is used) or to a file (if STORE is used).

grunt> A = load 'passwd' using PigStorage(':'); 
grunt> B = foreach A generate $0 as id; 
grunt> dump B; 
grunt> store B;
```

It not clear if I have to type in pig -x local to try out the grunt commands [May be pig has to run in one of the 2 modes but not obvious what to do out of the box]

After I type in

```
pig -x local
```

I get the grunt prompt but the commands fail saying :

```
 Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/home/<usr>/passwd
```

On searching Google, I get routed to mail archives like these:http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201109.mbox/%3C4E73658D.3000705@figarocms.fr%3E
These are hard to read and follow the conversation.

Here are 2 things I am looking for:
1] Is there a better guide to writing pig scripts and UDFs which holds your hand for a while [at least gets you through writing 1-2 UDFs for analyzing sample logs] before you get into wired errors . Any blog posts etc. what is a good starting point if say I have 4 hours to write few simple pig scripts 
2] For the error I am getting, may be I need to add the passwd file to HDFS? Unfortunately 
"hadoop fs -mkdir -p /home/" says the dir exist. So how do I put the file there now . Since I am running it in local mode, is there a way to just ask HDFS look files up on the paths I mention on my FS rather that putting files every time to HDFS ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When starting pig locally it will connect to you local file system:

```
user@machine~/pig-distrib$ pig -x local
12/08/23 10:10:24 INFO pig.Main: Apache Pig version 0.10.0 (r1328203) compiled Apr 19 2012, 22:54:12
12/08/23 10:10:24 INFO pig.Main: Logging error messages to: /home/user/pig-distrib/logs/pig.log
12/08/23 10:10:24 INFO executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
grunt> 
...
```

To locate passwd you have the following options:
1.
Copy `/etc/passwd` to the directory from where you execute pig shell and the you can issue:

```
grunt> A = load 'passwd' using PigStorage(':');
```

2.
Navigate to the directory in shell:

```
grunt> cd /etc
grunt> A = load 'passwd' using PigStorage(':');
```

3.
Or use the full path to your file:

```
grunt> A = load '/etc/passwd' using PigStorage(':');
```

You may also check these resources too:
http://www.cloudera.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/IntroToPig.pdf
[Programming Pig online notes](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/index.html)
http://parand.com/say/index.php/2008/06/19/pig-hadoop-commands-and-sample-results/